# ¿Por qué no detecta las colisiones?

Tags: unity

Estoy intentando hacer el juego de Pacman en Unity.
Hice una esfera y alrededor le pude 4 bloques pequeños. La idea es que cuando uno de estos bloques intercepte con algo, pacman detecte que tiene un muro adelante y pare de moverse en esa direccion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando apreta W, S, A o D se mueve en esa direccion.
En Update cuando se apreta una de estas teclas, se guarda la que se precionó en el char "direccion".
Luego se va a el metodo "moverPacman()", y dependiendo de lo que tenga direccion le cambia el transform.position a pacman para que se mueva.

Pacman tiene este script:

```
        public float speed = 1;
        public char direccion;
        public bool arriba, abajo, derecha, izquierda;

        void Start () {

            arriba = false;
            abajo = false;
            derecha = true;
            izquierda = false;
            direccion = 'D';
        }



        void Update () {

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
                direccion = 'W';
                arriba = true;
            }       
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
                direccion = 'S';
                abajo = true;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
                direccion = 'D';
                derecha = true;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
                direccion = 'A';
                izquierda = true;
            }

            moverPacman();
        }



    //METODOS---------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void moverPacman()
        {
            switch (direccion)
            {
                case 'W':
                    if (arriba) {
                        transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;

                        abajo = false;
                        derecha = false;
                        izquierda = false;

                    }
                    break;

                case 'S':
                    if (abajo) {
                        transform.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;

                        arriba = false;
                        derecha = false;
                        izquierda = false;
                    }
                    break;

                case 'D':
                    if(derecha){
                        transform.position += Vector3.right * speed *Time.deltaTime;

                        arriba = false;
                        abajo = false;
                        izquierda = false;
                    }
                    break;

                case 'A':
                        if(izquierda){
                        transform.position += Vector3.left * speed *Time.deltaTime;

                        arriba = false;
                        abajo = false;
                        derecha = false;

                        }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

A los cuadros que estan alrededor de pacman les puse esto. Cuando entran con contacto con el muro hace que la derecha sea igual a false y direccion = N para que no se mueva en esa direccion, y cuando ya no esta en contacto con el muro, manda derecha igual a true para que ahora si pueda volver a moverse en esa direccion. (Las otras 3 direcciones son iguales.)

**El problema es que cuando colisiona con el muro sigue moviendose como intentando atravesarlo en vez de parar cuando uno de los cuadros lo toque.**

Los cubos tienen este sript:

```
    movimientoPacman movimiento = new movimientoPacman();

        void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
        {
            movimiento.derecha = true;
        }
        void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
        {
            movimiento.derecha = false;
            movimiento.direccion = 'N';
        }
```

No se si tiene algo que ver que los cubos son hijos de pacman:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Muy buenas y bienvenido! Antes de contestarte, quería preguntarte si usas este código por alguna razón especial. Te lo pregunto por que lo que estás haciendo se puede simplificar mucho usando otro código y funcionalidades de Unity.

Comment: La verdad soy principiante en Unity así que no conozco todas las funcionalidades. Lo único es que mas adelante voy a necesitar que cuando lo ponga a moverse a una dirección hacia la que no pueda por estar al lado de un muro, que guarde ese movimiento y lo use cuando sí sea posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que estas haciendo es es posicionar el objeto en diferente lugar con position. Lo que tienes que hacer es colocar es el translate.

```
 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
            //direccion = 'W';
            //arriba = true;
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);

        }
```

Los cubos u objetos que quieras que colisionen deben llevar un código similar ha

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    print("¡Auch!");
}
```